# Does char == char implicitly cast both operands to int?

Tags: c++

I am freshening up my C++ skills, using a copy of the german book *"C++ - Das Übungsbuch"; 5. Auflage* from *mitp*.

Exercise 8.1 poses the following question (translated and reduced to the relevant content):

> **8.1** Given the following definition:
>
> `char c = 'q';`
>
> Determine the type to which the operands will be converted during evaluation of the following statements:
>
> **a)** `c == 'Q'`

My answer would have been `char`, as `c` is declared as a `char` and as far as I understood, `'Q'` is a character literal. The solution however states:

> **a)** The type of both operands will be converted to `int`

This confuses me. Is it really the case, that a `char == char` comparison is implicitly converted to `int == int` and why would this be done? If the question were

> **a)** `c == 82`

I could have understood that `82` would be interpreted as an integer constant and therefor `c` would be converted to `int` as well, but the answer explicitly mentions *both* operands to be converted.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Yes, technically both operands get casted to `int`. However, most compilers will not generate the actual code to do that, because a compiler is permitted to perform any optimization that has no observable effect, and it's pretty much impossible to observe the effect of this optimization. But, technically, both are promoted to int.

Comment: Just a bit of terminology: this question is about implicit **conversions**, not **casts**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. There is no such thing as an implicit cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you, I'll fix that. I already thought that cast wouldn't be the correct term here, but I was lost for the correct word, which you now provided. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is talking about [*usual arithmetic conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) which [happens if both operands have arithmetic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators) (which is true for all integer types, including `char`). That leads to [*integral promotion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Answer (score -5):

I think, that it uses for the comparison the ascii number corresponding to your character.
For example it converts q to 113 and Q to 81.
So it should compare:

```
'Q'=='q' //81==113
```

They are casted into integer because C interprets character as number of the ascii table.
See https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Comment: The question is about C++, and C and C++ behaves differently

Comment: I don't think this question is as much about internal `char` representation as it is about how integral comparisons work according to the standard.